# How to change the type of operands in the Callinst in llvm?

Tags: llvm

I am trying to implement a transformation of CallInst and perform the following:

1. Change the type of the arguments of function calls
2. Change the type of the return value

For example, I want to change the following IR:

```
    %call = call double @add(double %0, double %1)

    define double @add(double %x, double %y) #0 {
    entry:
      %x.addr = alloca double, align 8
      %y.addr = alloca double, align 8
      store double %x, double* %x.addr, align 8
      store double %y, double* %y.addr, align 8
      %0 = load double, double* %x.addr, align 8
      %1 = load double, double* %x.addr, align 8
      %add = fadd double %0, %1
      ret double %add
    }
```

To IR_New:

```
    %call = call x86_fp80 @new_add(x86_fp80 %0, x86_fp80 %1)

    define x86_fp80 @new_add(x86_fp80 %x, x86_fp80 %y) #0 {
    entry:
      %x.addr = alloca x86_fp80, align 16
      %y.addr = alloca x86_fp80, align 16
      store x86_fp80 %x, x86_fp80* %x.addr, align 16
      store x86_fp80 %y, x86_fp80* %y.addr, align 16
      %0 = load x86_fp80, x86_fp80* %x.addr, align 16
      %1 = load x86_fp80, x86_fp80* %x.addr, align 16
      %add = fadd x86_fp80 %0, %1
      ret x86_fp80 %add
    }
```

I have finished changing the type of AllocaInst, StoreInst, LoadInst, BinaryOperator and ReturnInst.

I am now very confused about how to deal with CallInst.

My original idea is when iterating all the instructions, if I find a CallInst,

```
   if (CallInst *call = dyn_cast<CallInst>(it)){
```

do the following three steps:

1. Construct the new FunctionType

   ```
   x86_fp80(x86_fp80, x86_fp80)
   ```

   using

   ```
   std::vector<Type*> ParamTys;
   ParamTys.push_back(Type::getX86_FP80Ty(context));
   ParamTys.push_back(Type::getX86_FP80Ty(context));
   FunctionType *new_fun_type = FunctionType::get(Type::getX86_FP80Ty(context), ParamTys, true);
   ```
2. Construct function with new type in Step 1, i.e. construct new_add in the example

   ```
   Function *fun = call->getCalledFunction();
   Function *new_fun = Function::Create(new_fun_type,fun->getLinkage(), "", fun->getParent());
   ```
3. Construct a new CallInst with the new function obtained from step 2.

   ```
   CallInst *new_call = CallInst::Create(new_fun, *arrayRefOperands, "newCall", call);
   new_call->takeName(call);
   }
   ```

However, in this way, I got the following IR instead of the IR_New I want:

```
   %call = call x86_fp80 (x86_fp80, x86_fp80, ...) @0(x86_fp80 %5, x86_fp80 %7)

   declare x86_fp80 @new_add(x86_fp80, x86_fp80, ...)
```

A new definition of called function is constructed(declare x86_fp80 @new_add(x86_fp80, x86_fp80, ...)), but the body of this new function is empty. I am very confused how to add the body and get the IR_New I want. My naive idea is:

```
   for (Instruction i : called function(add in the example)){
       create new_i with type x86_fp80;
       insert new_i in the new function constructed(new_add in the example);
     }
```

Is this a good way to achieve my goal?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use llvm::Value::mutateType(llvm::Ty) to change double type value to x86_fp80 if you are no longer using the original function somewhere else.
goto function definition using CallInst->getCalledFunction() and iterate over all value then mutate double types to x86_fp80.

ref: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html#ac0f09c2c9951158f9eecfaf7068d7b20

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. However, it is said mutating type directly is very dangerous. So in my code, I create a new function with the new type I want. Doesn't it work?  I think my problem lies in how to create the body of the new function, right? Could you give me some advice if there is an elegant way to do this? Many thanks :)

Comment: You can also use llvm::CloneFunction(const llvm::Function, ValueToValueMapTy*..) this does NOT add function to current module, you can set return function name using clone->setname(string) and then add to Current module function list using Module->getFunctionList()->push_bask(clone), here ValueToValueMapTy are used for references to specify the map which are changed in cloned function. for more info see  (ref: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a5596246c2350cb74f31ffa7695d5923c)

Comment: Other variants of CloneFunction are also present you can use them as per your requirement.

Comment: I tried your method in the answer, but it causes runtime error of return type and operand type doesn't match very easily. For example, mutate the type of the function foo

double foo(double x){
double y = x;
return y;
}

There are two steps, 1) mutate the declaration of foo to long double(long double x) using mutateType()
2) mutate the return instruction in the function body to long double

No matter I do step 1) first or step 2) first, there are core dump errors. Since two steps must be done in one statement to make the types match.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. I have a puzzle about the CloneFunction method. Do you mean I need to do the type mutating on the clone function? BTW, what do you think my idea at the end of the post? Many thanks :)

Comment: Yes you are right, mutatetype method should NOT be used. Clone function method you can traverse through original function and create ValueToValueMapTy(typedef ValueMap< const Value*, WeakVH >  llvm::ValueToValueMapTy) check if value is of double then add it to the map map[orig]=undefval::get(x86_fp80 type), weakVH will null itself out if the value is destroyed, pass this map to clone function call which implicitly convert type (mutating is NOT needed), add clone func to module's func list. if copy of func is required with few changes, then i think clone function is way to do it. Cheers. :)

Comment: I find that if the called function calls another function, clonefunction() method will not work :(

Comment: can you conform if it solves the example you have listed in question?  also if the function you are changing calls another function in module and/or depends on link time library functions, you can check for call method and depending on your requirement you can clone the calling function or just change the arguments and return type of call inst using fpext/fptrunc (double <--> float). and also i suggest you create a new thread or modify the current one to accommodate your queries so other with new solutions can post.